# How can I get next three working days in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I'm new to typescript. I wrote this code to get the next three working days(Sunday is not a working day). But it is not working. Can someone suggest an alternative solution?

```
today = new Date()
day1 = get_next_working_day(today)
day2 = get_next_working_day(day1)
day3 = get_next_working_day(day2)

function get_next_working_day(day){
  const temp = new Date(day.setDate(day.getDate()+1) )
  if(temp.getDay() == 0){
    return get_next_working_day(temp)
  }
  return temp
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setDate` on a date, it modifies the date object itself. So your code will always change today's date to be tomorrow. Try this instead

```
function get_next_working_day(day){

  const temp = new Date(day);
  temp.setDate(temp.getDate()+1);//Modifies temp valur
  if(temp.getDay() == 0){
    return get_next_working_day(temp);
  }
  return temp;
}
```